# What are the PDFs of multivariate continuous Gaussian random vectors?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

Let, $X_{i}$ is a vector of random variables, where $i= 1,2,3,...,n$.

$1$. What would be $PDF(x)$, if $X_i$ is dependent?

$2$. What would be $PDF(x)$, if $X_i$ is independent?

$3$. What would be $PDF(x)$, if $X_i$ is Parzen?

---

N.B. I only need correct formulas. Coz, I am confused with so many varieties of them.

Comment: For (2) you can multiply the marginal densities

Comment: This question of mine has been able to demonstrate the bankruptcy of this web-site!!